# Editing the current page on view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am working on an viewpager with previous and next page. What I need is to increase the text of the current page, after loading the page. But while I am trying, text on the next page is changing (I know that next and previous page load on viewpager). How can I get the focused on one selected page? 
What I have done is,

```
viewPager.setClipChildren(false);
```

unfortunately it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

i didn't really understand what you need but i think you may use this:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
           //Edit
            if(position==int requiredPosition)
            {
                 // resize your text
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: hi
i need to change the text size while pressing a button, after loading the page. the problem is it happens in next page, while i am trying to do

Comment: what kind of object does your viewpager handle? like fragments or what?

Comment: one image , 8 buttons 2 texts,

Answer (score 0):

I recommed using position parameter in activity and you can update text based on the position recieved.

**This example is for Fragments though**

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
```

And in fragment you recieve this position as an argument:

```
public static PageFragment newInstance(int position) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("position", position);
    PageFragment page = new PageFragment();
    page.setArguments(args);
    return page;
}
```

In onCreateView you update your textview based on your position.

If you want to update TextView something like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourId);
int position = getArguments().getInt("position");
tv.setText("This is page number: " + position);
```

Comment: I updated my answer, hope this helps. You can also do more complex updates like if (position == 2) //do something different

Comment: i am getting the page no. but the result still on the next page. The current focus is on next page . i want the focus on current page . that what i want